# JQuery DataTable - How to Save a Table in Excel with Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using DataTable JQuery.
I'm able to save the table in Excel without problem.
However the excel downloaded doesn't have any formatting in it.
Like I want to set font colors and column width of the excel.
Please kindly help. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tableBD1").dataTable( {
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": "../js/DataTables-1.10.0/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                      {
                        "sExtends": "xls",
                        "sButtonText": "Export to Excel",
                        "sFileName": "MyReport.csv",
                        "oSelectorOpts": {
                            page: 'current'
                         }
                      }
                 ]
            }
        } );
    } );
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot. Basically the "excel"-download is just a tabulator separated CSV, the "CSV" is (by default) a semicolon separated CSV. No options for styling, and certainly no options for setting column-widths. You must create a download by your own, converting the content of the table to xlsx-format, using PHPExcel or similar library according to what serverside language you are using.

Comment: David is absolutely right - not possible unless you use powerfull back-end xlsx file creator. @Jemru, don't forget to reward the guys who was helpfull with the upvote - this gives reputation :)